# como dar estilo a contenido de ActionLinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Puedo hacer modificaciones de estilo solo al contenido de mi actionLink?, en este caso a la palabra Excel..ya que al dar un estilo modifica a todo mi ActionLink, icono y texto.
Código

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel  ", "ExportarConsultaAlmacen", new { formato = "Excel" }, new { @class = "fa fa-file-excel-o btn btn-default" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo recordar que esto es razor, mira, lo mejor es que lo ejecutes en el navegador la página, y mires el HTML que genera el control ActionLink (Para mirar el html usar el modo desarrollador dandole a F12).

Como ya sabes, todos los controles de .net al final acaban traduciendose en HTML.

Una vez identificado, es tan fácil como darle estilo con CSS.

Un saludo.